# Previous names on US passport renewal form

Tags: us-citizens, passport-renewals

After 2 marriages I took my maiden name back. I have remarried for the 3rd time but kept my maiden name.

On line 9 of form DS82, do I just put previous married names? On line 11, 'name change information', when it asks whether the name change is by marriage or court order, do I list both divorce dates or just the last one when I reverted to my maiden name?

Comment: Line 9.... means very little without reference to a particular form. I looked up [Passport Forms](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/how-apply/forms.html) but the DS82 passport renewal doesn't seem to have a relevant line 9.

Comment: @WeatherVane What? DS82's line 9 is "list all other names you have used" https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds82.pdf

Comment: Did you change your name twice since your previous passport was issued?

Comment: At what point did you resume using your maiden name, right after the 2nd marriage or right after the 3rd marriage. Is there an official document like a divorce decree or marriage certificate that specifically says you stopped using one of your married names and started using your maiden name?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for [DB82's line 9](https://eforms.state.gov/Forms/ds82.pdf) says:

> List all other names you have used: Enter all legal names previously
> used to include maiden name, name changes, and previous married names.
> You can enter up to two names: one in item A and one in item B. If
> only your last name has changed just enter the last name. If you need
> more space to write additional names, please use a separate sheet of
> paper and attach it to this form.

If your current passport uses your maiden name, you can probably just list your two married names because you don't need to document the name change back to your maiden name.

If your current passport is not using your current name, you should list all three names, which means attaching a separate piece of paper listing the third one, and including the documentation for your most recent name change.

For line 11 which asks about how the latest name change occurred, you should use the divorce decree/court order when you changed back to your maiden name.

Comment: The current name will be listed in item 1.  There is no need to list it again in item 9.  The only name change that has to be documented is the change from the name in which the previous passport was issued to the current name.